# Returning an Array within an Array inside a JSON file with jQuery AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm desperately trying to return an array within another array inside of a JSON file. The problem is, I keep getting [object, object] displayed instead of the actual text/content inside of the object. I do not understand why all my other requests are able to return JSON data fine, but when it is inside of another array, it changes to [Object, object] format. I really would appreciate some help GREATLY!

```
$.ajax({
  url: "HIDDEN-URL&format=jsonp",
  type: "get",
  async: true,
  contentType: "application/jsonp",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.programs.program.requirements);
    ////// TAB 1 //////  
    // return title
    $('.wrapper').append('<div class="overview"> ' + data.programs.program.requirements[0].title + ' </div>');
    // return content
    $('.wrapper').append('<div class="overview"> ' + data.programs.program.requirements[0].content + ' </div>');
    ////// TAB 2 //////  
    // return title
    $('.wrapper').append('<div class="overview"> ' + data.programs.program.requirements[1].title + ' </div>');
    // return content
    $('.wrapper').append('<div class="overview"> ' + data.programs.program.requirements[1].content + ' </div>');
    ////// TAB 3 //////  
    // return title
    $('.wrapper').append('<div class="overview"> ' + data.programs.program.requirements[2].title + ' </div>');
    // return content
    $('.wrapper').append('<div class="overview"> ' + data.programs.program.requirements[2].requirement_list + ' </div>');
  }
});
```

[Image of the console log and page with [Object, object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUBPo.png)

Comment: The last jQuery selector is the one that is not returning JSON data correctly.

Comment: `data.programs.program.requirements[2].requirement_list` this is an array list you need to loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `data.programs.program.requirements[2].requirement_list`is an array of object. You need to use a loop to return all the items.

**UPDATE**

For nested loop:

```
data.programs.program.requirements.map(function(requirement){
    requirement.requirement_list.map(function(item){
        $('.wrapper').append('<div class="overview"> ' + item.title + ' </div>');
    });
});
```

Comment: OMG TY. Your using the ES6 map method as well, which is totally awesome. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What if the results are also an array of objects?

Comment: Then you have to create nasty loop, for each item in the array, you call the inner loop to add requirement_list items

Comment: I’ve been trying to do that, would have any example? This is one hell of a beast, never seen a monster like it before! Thank you for the tip. So appreciated!!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to call the inner loop? I cannot find information on it anywhere.

Comment: I updated my answer. This should allow you to go over each requirements and append each requirement_list item to the html.

Comment: Thanks you so much, this really boggled my mind and I’m so happy to see it work. I tried similar things but never was successful. So appreciated, I wish you great luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate an array with a string. The problem ist that arrays and objects will not get translated into strings during the concat process. You have to call JSON.stringify on the object explicitly.

```
$('.wrapper').append('<div class="overview"> ' + JSON.stringify(data.programs.program.requirements[2].requirement_list) + ' </div>');
```

Another possibility:

```
 data.programs.program.requirements[2].requirement_list.map(requ => $('.wrapper').append('<div class="overview"> ' + requ.title + ' </div>') );
```